# Can I pass non-graphics PCI-E without host drivers to virtualbox vm on FreeBSD

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, freebsd, pci-express

Like the question says, I have a pci-e card with windows (but not freeBSD) drivers. Can it be passed through from a host running FreeBSD 10.3 or higher to a VirtualBox VM running Windows 8.1/10?

The only similar questions I can find cover USB devices (yes) and graphics cards (no as they may need to be shared with the host). I can't find an answer for non-graphics cards.

**Update** the card in question is a TBS tv tuner card, which runs in windows and has windows drivers and software but not freebsd drivers. (It also has Linux drivers but a Linux VM would pose similar issues so that's a last resort). It doesn't have TV out or graphics out, or not that I use, it's a pure tuner card

Comment: Generally speaking the answer is no, but can you be more specific as to the card you are referring to?

Comment: Updated question - hopefully possible?

Comment: OK... Is FreeBSD the host and Windows the virtual environment, or the other way around? And which one does it need to work in?

Comment: Clarified above and added a bit more detail

Comment: Hmm... I have no way to test this in a FreeBSD environment nor do I  have a similar card, but in a Linux install it may be possible with a VirtualBox Extension pack if certain criteria are met according, according to https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough